# N-1 queen on the chessboard

Tags: logical-deduction, chess

You are trying to solve the famous N  queens problem. You broke one of the queens from your chess pieces collections. Now, you have created the following puzzle:

You are given an N*N  chessboard. Is it possible to place N-1 queens on it in such a way that no pair of queens is attacking each other?

Two queens are attacking each other if at least one of the following conditions is true:

They share the same row
They share the same column
They share the same diagonal
You are given a single integer N. Print any possible configuration in the format below. It is guaranteed that there is always an answer

for example N=4.
one of the possible answer is

```
* . . .
. . * .
. . . .
. * . .
```

Comment: Of course N-1 queens are possible: just pick a solution of N queens then remove one of them.

Comment: @athin but how to print that pattern

Comment: Printing patterns makes me wonder.. Is it from a programming contest, in some sense?

Comment: @athin yes, it is . van u please help me how to print patterns

Comment: In that case, could you give first which contest does this come from? Otherwise the question might be closed as a result of not having a proper attribution. I also want to help, but if this is from an on-going competition then we need to wait until it's over too.

Comment: @athin it is hackerearth problem assignment ,not contest

Comment: If you need help with constructing a program to solve this problem, then it would be better to ask on a programming site, not on a puzzle site. You can find many programs for the standard N-queens problem very easily. Once you understand how those programs work, try to adapt one them to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

> Note that the $N$ queens problem is always solvable except for $N=2$ and $3$, so by removing any queen from the solution we get a valid $N-1$ queens solution. For $N=2$, it's trivial to place $2-1=1$ queen into any square. For $N=3$, it's sufficient to place $3-1=2$ queens at a distance of a knight's move, so they would not attack each other.

Comment: can u help me how to print patterns

Comment: @trolley813 Note that your solution method is not necessarily reversible, so there will usually also be solutions to the N-1 queens problem that cannot be generated in this way. The 4x4 example in the problem statement is one example.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It's sufficient but not necessary to build a full N-queen solution, there are positions with N-1 queens where it's impossible to add the Nth queen.